# Double sort (Sort elements on 2 different values)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have a struct **node** that looks like this:

```
typedef struct node{
    int t;
    double p;
}node;
```

And then I also have an array of `struct node` some of which have equal values *p*.

**What I want to do is:**

Primarily, sort the elements based on value *p*. And after I have a sorted array based on *p*, I want every sub-array with the same *p* to be sorted based on value *t*.

**For example:**

If I have original array that looks like this (1st element is *p*, 2nd element is *t*):

[0,10|1],  [0.05|0],  [0,10|0],  [0,05|2],  [0,10|2],  [0,15|1],  [0,05|1]

After it is double sorted, it should look like this:

[0,05|0],  [0,05|1],  [0,05|2],  [0,10|0],  [0,10|1],  [0,10|2],  [0,15|1].

I have come up with the bubble sort based on *p*, but I then have difficulties on how to sort sub-arrays on *t*. Here is bubble sort code on *p*.

```
node *sort_p(node *nodes, int num) {
    int i, j;
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));

    for(i=1; i<num; i+=1){
        for(j=0; j<num-i; j+=1){
            if(nodes[j].p > nodes[j+1].p){
                *temp = nodes[j];
                nodes[j] = nodes[j+1];
                nodes[j+1] = *temp;
            }
        }
    }
    free(temp);

    return nodes;
}
```

How could I accomplish the desired double sort?

**UPDATE**

I wrote a compare method that works with *qsort()* as suggested below, but it does not yield the desired results from one point.

I am calling the method like this: `qsort(nodes, num_of_nodes, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);`

Where `compare_pairs()` looks like this:

```
static int compare_pairs(node *n1, node *n2){

const node *na1 = n1;
const node *na2 = n2;

if(na1->p< na2->p) return -1;
if(na1->p> na2->p) return 1;

if(na1->t < na2->t) return -1;
if(na1->t > na2->t) return 1;

return 0;
```

**Problem**

**The unwanted behaviour starts at *3. STEP* which looks like this:**

**List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]**

**And should look like this:**

**List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]**

Initial list:
[0.25 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05| 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Creating (new) node 0.100000...

List: [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.10 | 1]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Creating (new) node 0.100000...

List: [0.05 | 999]  [0.10 | 1]  [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Creating (new) node 0.150000...

List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (new) node 0.200000...

List: [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Creating (new) node 0.250000...

List: [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Erasing (new) node 0.300000...

List: [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]  [0.30 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.200000...

Erasing (min) node 0.250000...

Erasing (new) node 0.450000...

List: [0.25 | 999]  [0.30 | 1]  [0.45 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.250000...

Erasing (min) node 0.300000...

Creating (new) node 0.550000...

List: [0.45 | 1]  [0.55 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.450000...

Erasing (min) node 0.550000...

Creating (new) node 1.000000...

List: [1.00 | 1]

*General idea**

In every step two minimal nodes get deleted from list, and one new node gets inserted into the list. The node that gets inserted has the value of *t* for 1 bigger then the greatest in the list, except that it does not compare itself to the *t* value of 999. If the greatest in the list has *t* = 999, then the one inserted will have 1.

*Find greatest t*:

```
int max_t(node *nodes, int num, double p){
int max_t= 0;
int i;
for(i=0; i<num; i+=1){
    if(nodes[i].p== p && nodes[i].t != 999){
        if(nodes[i].t > max_t){
            max_t = nodes[i].t;
        }
    }
}
return max_t;
```

Main code:

```
node *nodes = malloc(num_of_nodes*sizeof(node));
int i;
for(i=0; i<num_of_nodes; i+=1){
    node n;
    n.t = 999;
    n.p = *(probabs+ i);
    *(nodes+i) = n;
}

qsort(nodes, num_of_nodes, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);

while(num_of_nodes> 1){

    printf("\n%d. STEP:\n", z);
    z += 1;

    // 2) Find two min nodes
    node *min_n1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *min_n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));

    *min_n1 = nodes[0];
    printf("Erasing (min) node %lf...\n", min_n1->p);
    nodes= erase_node(nodes, min_n1, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes -= 1;

    *min_n2 = nodes[0];
    printf("Erasing (min) node %lf...\n", min_n2->p);
    nodes= erase_node(nodes, min_n2, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes-= 1;

    // 3) Create new node, add it to the list
    node *new:node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->p= min_n1->p + min_n2->p;
    double p = new->p;
    int max_t = max_t(nodes, num_of_nodes, p);
    new_node->t = max_t + 1;

    printf("Creating (new) node %lf...\n", new_node->p);
    node = add_node(nodes, new_node, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes += 1;

    qsort(nodes, num_of_nodes, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);

    printf("List: ");
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<num_of_nodes; k+=1){
        printf("[%.2lf | %d]  ", nodes[k].p, nodes[k].t);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is needlessly complicated. There's no need to "sort twice", all you need to do is enhance the comparison operator.

Also, use `qsort()` to sort arrays in C, it's much easier than rolling your own sort, and might have better performance too.

Basically, you should try to fill in the blanks of a function like this:

```
static int compare_pairs(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const node *na = a, *nb = b;

  /* more code here */
}
```

Essentially you have the solution when you say "I want every sub-array with the same p to be sorted based on value t".

That means the body of the comparison function becomes:

```
if(na->p < nb->p)
  return -1;
if(na->p > nb->p)
  return 1;
/* If we get this far, we know the p values are equal, so tie-break with t. */
if(na->t < nb->t)
  return -1;
if(na->t > nb->t)
  return 1;
return 0;
```

Finally, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).